# AWS Lambda API Gateway Define Path Parameters Node Js - Not Working

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

I have tried following the documentation to have path parameters filter the dynamodb scan.

I am trying to filter on userID. I have used API gateway to use the path as a parameter {userID} and used lambda to look for the path parameter to filter. When I hardcode a userID in the lambda function it works perfectly so there seems to be a disconnect in the function getting the path parameter.

lambda function:

[image: lambda function]

apigateway path:

[image: apigateway path]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

usually "$input.params" uses in body mapping templates. You can create a body mapping template in integration request and you can get params inside Lambda function like an event.UserID,

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html#input-variable-reference